# Вывод сообщений из БД через ajax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, база-данных

При нажатии на кнопку "отправить" которая в свою очередь отправляет данные через ajax в БД и тут же должно их вытягивать и отобразить в мини-чате как сообщение.Но при отправке начинает выводить вот такую вот ошибку. Uncaught ReferenceError: send is not defined
На просторах годного не нашел ничего.Как с этим быть не знаю

```
// Форма
<div class="form-control" id="messages"  style="min-height: 100px;"><p><br></p></div>
<p><form  action="javascript:send();"  method="post"></p>
<input type="text" id="soob" class="form-control">
<p><button id="mes_send" type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-5">
    Отправить
</button></p>
</form>

//Ajax
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$('#mes_send').click(function () {
var soob = $ ('#soob').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'reg/chat.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {'soob' : soob},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#soob").val('');
    }
});

});

</script>
<script>
function load_messes()
{
  $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url:  "reg/add_mess.php",
              data: {'id' : id},

              success: function(html)
      {

        // $("#messages").empty();

        $("#messages").append(html);

        $("#messages").scrollTop(90000);
              }
      });
}
</script>


//php для добавления в бд

<?

if(isset($_POST['soob'])){

$soob = $_POST['soob'];
require_once '../mysql.php';

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `chat`(`soob`) VALUES(?)";
  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute([$soob]);

}



  ?>


// php Для выводы из бд
<?php

require_once '../mysql.php';

$res="SELECT * FROM `soob` ORDER BY `id` ";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(['id' =>$id]);


$out = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($out as $key) {
echo "<div class='alert alert-info mb-2'>

<p>"$key->soob"</p>
</div>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="soob" class="form-control">
  <p><button id="mes_send" type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-5">
    Отправить
  </button></p>
</form>
```